# Getting blank output in VectorPlot3D

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to do a vector plot of a given vector field for which I wrote following code

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y -1)^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 1)^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2]
VectorPlot3D[Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

But I'm getting following output [image]

Where am I making the mistake and I have also tried restarting the kernel?

Edit: I got around the problem by going through the method of tables. The code is:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y -1)^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 1)^2 + z^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + y^2 + (z - 1)^2] + 1/Sqrt[(x - 1)^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 1)^2 + (z - 1)^2]
h = Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];
vectors = Table[-h, {x, -0.13, 1.13, 0.05}, {y, -.13, 1.13, 0.05}, {z, -.13, 1.13, 0.05}];
ListVectorPlot3D[vectors, VectorScale -> {Small, 0.6, Automatic}, VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

and the output looks like: [image: c]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
VectorPlot3D[Evaluate@Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}], 
      {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1,1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nope I'm still getting the same single vector in the output.

Comment: @aitfel I am sorry to hear that. But as you can see, it works for me. May be version difference. I could try on what I have, which is V 12.1

Comment: I did get the result but by using ListVectorPlot3D